# How to add more parameters to addEventListener's functions? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, parameters, load, addeventlistener

I have a problem when I work with `uploadDisplay_SP_reply_'.$statusid.'`
As you can see these divs has unique id `($statusid)` which is auto increment so if I want to display an image inside a specific `div` in Javascript addEventListener's function the program won't know in which div should it display the image. And here is my problem. In other functions I could add this unique id e.g `(replytext_'.$statusid.')` in PHP and `function showBtnDiv_reply(e)` in Javascript where e is `$statusid`, but in the `function completeHandler_reply` I can't. The `function completeHandler_reply` only gets one parameter from the addEventListener which is the `event`. So how can I add the `$statusid` to `function completeHandler_reply` or is there any way I can solve it?

PHP:

```
if($isFriend == true || $log_username == $u){
        $statuslist .= '<textarea id="replytext_'.$statusid.'" class="replytext" onfocus="showBtnDiv_reply('.$statusid.')" placeholder="Write a comment..."></textarea>';
        $statuslist .= '<div id="uploadDisplay_SP_reply_'.$statusid.'"></div>';
        $statuslist .= '<div id="btns_SP_reply_'.$statusid.'" class="hiddenStuff">';
            $statuslist .= '<button id="replyBtn_'.$statusid.'" class="btn_rply" onclick="replyToStatus('.$statusid.',\''.$u.'\',\'replytext_'.$statusid.'\',this)">Reply</button>';
            $statuslist .= '<img src="images/camera.png" id="triggerBtn_SP_reply" class="triggerBtn" onclick="triggerUpload_reply(event, \'fu_SP_reply\')" width="22" height="22" title="Upload A Photo" />';
        $statuslist .= '</div>';
        $statuslist .= '<div id="standardUpload_reply" class="hiddenStuff">';
            $statuslist .= '<form id="image_SP_reply" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">';
            $statuslist .= '<input type="file" name="FileUpload" id="fu_SP_reply" onchange="doUpload_reply(\'fu_SP_reply\','.$statusid.')"/>';
            $statuslist .= '</form>';
        $statuslist .= '</div>';    
        }
    }
```

Javascript:

I can add the `$statusid` here as a parameter `e`

```
function showBtnDiv_reply(e){
    _("replytext_"+e).style.height = "130px";
    _("btns_SP_reply_"+e).style.display = "block";
}

function doUpload_reply(id,sid){
    var file = _(id).files[0];
    if(file.name == ""){
        return false;       
    }

    if(file.type != "image/jpeg" && file.type != "image/gif" && file.type != "image/png" && file.type != "image/jpg"){
        alert("That file type is not supported.");
        return false;
    }
    _("triggerBtn_SP_reply").style.display = "none";
    _("uploadDisplay_SP_reply_"+sid).innerHTML = '<img src="images/rolling.gif" width="30" height="30">';
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("stPic_reply", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler_reply, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler_reply, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler_reply, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "php_parsers/photo_system.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);    
}
```

But here I can't add the `$statusid` as a 2nd parameter next to `event`

```
function completeHandler_reply(event){
    var data = event.target.responseText;
    var datArray = data.split("|");
    if(datArray[0] == "upload_complete"){
        hasImage = datArray[1];
        _("uploadDisplay_SP_reply").innerHTML = '<img src="tempUploads/'+datArray[1]+'" class="statusImage" />';
    } else {
        _("uploadDisplay_SP_reply").innerHTML = datArray[0];
        _("triggerBtn_SP_reply").style.display = "block";
    }
}

function errorHandler_reply(event){
    _("uploadDisplay_SP_reply_").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
    _("triggerBtn_SP_reply").style.display = "block";
}

function abortHandler_reply(event){
    _("uploadDisplay_SP_reply").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
    _("triggerBtn_SP_reply").style.display = "block";
}
```

I've tried it but didn't work for me.

```
function completeHandler_reply(event,sid){
    _("uploadDisplay_SP_reply_"+sid);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an anonymouse function within the `eventListener` and then call the actual function from within that function.

```
ajax.addEventListener("load", function(event){
    completeHandler_reply.call( this, arg1,arg2,arg3 );
}, false );

or 

ajax.addEventListener("load", function(event){
    completeHandler_reply.apply( this, [ arg1, arg2, arg3 ] );
}, false );
```

Passing in whatever arguments are appropriate ~ I used `arg1` etc as an example

Comment: This works but why I have to add .call or .apply after my completeHandler_reply function? What do these?

Comment: You do not need to do so - I always tend to do that but it's neither here nor there. More info from MDN ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: And how will my completeHandler_reply function know what is e.g sid if I use sid instead of arg1? I mean if we have a look at one of my functions in the code above then we can see that every function that has sid or e as a parameter that called in the PHP form e.g doUpload_reply(\'fu_SP_reply\','.$statusid.') and the Javascript form below doUpload_reply(id,sid). And my function will know what is sid ($statusid) and what is id(fu_reply). But if I just set a parameter as sid in the completeHandler_reply function that will give me an error. Or can I use completeHandler_reply('.$statusid.')?

Comment: And I didn't call completeHandler_reply anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

how about using anonymous function instead? try this:

```
ajax.addEventListener("load", function (event){
    _("uploadDisplay_SP_reply_"+sid);
}, false);
```